# "Requires no" vs "doesn't require"

Tags: meaning, word-request, difference

Is there a difference between "requires no" and "doesn't require" as in "The thing requires no other thing"? If no, how to convey the requirement of the absence of the other thing?

Comment: It is a more emphatic and concise way of phrasing many similar sentences: "I don't ask for any favours" – "I ask for no favours".

Comment: As a general principle, I'm sure native Anglophones much prefer to ***negate the verb*** rather than *"**nullify the object**"* in instructions and descriptions. Hence it's ***Don't pick the flowers, He doesn't eat meat, I can't hear a sound***, rather than ***Pick no flowers, He eats no meat, I can hear no sound*** (those last three are all "stylised, literary" forms that simply wouldn't occur in "normal" contexts).

Comment: BUT - English isn't at all good at conveying "the ***requirement*** of the absence of some other thing". So I can easily say ***Whatever she cooks you don't need to add salt***, but I'd probably need a lot more words to convey that adding salt at the table would be ***unacceptable***, rather than simply ***unnecessary***.